# Static const without initializer

Tags: c++, constants, static-initialization

In C you can do this:

```
static const int a;

int main(){}
```

And it seems to be fine. C99 §6.7.8p10 says:

> If an object that has static storage duration is not initialized
>   explicitly, then:
>
> — if it has arithmetic type, it is initialized to (positive or
>   unsigned) zero;

Similarly C++14 §3.6.2p2 says:

> Variables with static storage duration (3.7.1) or thread storage
>   duration (3.7.2) shall be zero-initialized (8.5) before any other
>   initialization takes place.

The difference is in C++14 it needs an initializer §8.5p7:

> If a program calls for the default initialization of an object of a
>   const-qualified type `T`, `T` shall be a class type with a
>   user-provided default constructor.

So I'm asking why is an initializer required in C++? No initializer is required if `a` is not `const`, so what difference does `const` make here that would make no initializer bad?

Comment: C and C++ are different languages.

Answer (score 0):

In the general case of a class type object, zero-initialization may not yield a valid object. And if such a class has no default constructor, then a `static const` of that type without an initializer, would produce an invalid object.

The current rules just *don't add* an exception for types where zero-initialization is good enough.

An extra language feature to support zero constants would complicate things for no real gain.

Answer (score -1):

C is not a very safe language. In C, an initializer is not required for a `const` object. Meaning you can do this:

```
int main()
{
    const int a;
}
```

Oops. `a` has automatic storage duration, so it has an indeterminate value. And you can't change it later...

Now let's say you allowed this feature. Would it make sense? Well unlike C, C++ has a concept called *constant initialization* that is sometimes performed instead of zero initialization. But what do you expect the value of `a` to have? Indeterminate value? It can't be zero since we just said that doesn't happen!

If you want `a` to be zero, then just ***say so***. Don't rely on implicit rules of the language which (in C's case) are  inconsistent. That's bad for readability and maintainability.

Comment: The question is about a **file scope** variable, not an auto variable. File scope `int` variables get initialized to 0, so all this talk about indeterminate values is irrelevant.